# Magento 2 disabled shipping option after changing State of a new shipping address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

In the checkout page, I found that the radio buttons of shipping options will be disabled after changing State/Provice of a new address if "tablerate" shipping method is used.
Is there any method to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Reason behind for that particular Shipping Address' Country Rates are not available

Comment: But it showed correct shipping rates.